# Apache Math Commons: non-linear optimization

Tags: optimization, partial-derivative, jacobian

I want to fit the following function:

$f(K) = e^{-qTS} - e^{rTK}$

i.e. find the parameters $q$ and $r$ to minimize the error.

$T$ and $S$ are constants.

I am using the Apache Math Commons library (which I am new to), but if I understood it well, first I need to calculate the Jacobian matrix.

My partial derivatives by $q$ and $r$ look like this:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial q}(K) = -TSe^{-qTS}$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(K) = TKe^{rTK}$

I am not sure how to proceed since these are non-linear equations, and since my partial derivatives factor $q$ and $r$ themselves. Is this correct or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the library uses [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) sort of optimization, given that the [creation function](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/fitting/SimpleCurveFitter.html#create(org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.ParametricUnivariateFunction,%20double[])) asks for "Initial guess for the parameters."

I suppose a natural guess would be $[0,0]$ for $q, r$.

You also need to provide a "[ParametricUnivariateFunction](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/ParametricUnivariateFunction.html)", which will be a class with two methods to implement. Fortunately, you've done the hard work in implementing them!

You'll want to write the [value](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/ParametricUnivariateFunction.html#value(double,%20double...)) function, which takes in $K$ and $[q,r]$ and returns the value for $f(K) = e^{-qTS} - e^{rTK}$. Which is easy to write! You will want to check that the array is length $2$ exactly, and you'll be hard-coding that $q$ is first and $r$ is second...

Second part is writing the [gradient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/ParametricUnivariateFunction.html#gradient(double,%20double...)). Which you've basically done! Just return an array with the values $[-TSe^{-qTS}, TKe^{rTK}]$, again you're getting $K$ and $[q,r]$ as input. (And again, check that the input array is length two).

That's it! You can probably futz around a bit with code quality for a while, but it's just a simple Java class of two stateless functions. Good luck with whatever the thing you're doing is.

Note: If the function was a two-valued function with two variables, and you took the derivative wrt those two variables, and you took the derivative of the resulting matrix, *that* would be a Jacobian.